# I installed tcWebHooks on TeamCity, options not showing

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm using *TeamCity Professional 9.0.2 (build 32195)*.

I installed the tcWebHooks plugin:
[image]

But I do not see any changes to the admin, and I cannot determine where to add web hooks to my build. I see no additional options in either the Project configuration or the Build configuration. Did I miss a step? From what I'm reading in the documentation, it should be a Project level setting with additions to the Project Home view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with the 0.9.27.61 version of tcWebHooks. I installed 0.9.18.165 and everything works as expected.

Comment: This solved it for me as well. I also noticed that the vendor and version strings are missing with 0.9.27.61, but are present with 0.9.18.165.

Answer (score 1):

It's in a weird spot in TeamCity for some reason. You go under a `Build Project`, without going into `Edit Project Settings`.

EDIT: I'd also check the tcWebHooks blog for more info: https://netwolfuk.wordpress.com/category/teamcity/tcplugins/tcwebhooks/

[image]

Comment: I am looking at the same view and I do not see Build Chains, WebHooks, or HipChat. I wonder if I need to reinstall the plugin.

Comment: Which version of tcWebHooks do you have installed? It looks like the version I am trying to use is 0.9.27.61

Comment: @MikeCole I'm using 0.9.18.165.

Comment: @MikeCole check the tcWebHooks blog?https://netwolfuk.wordpress.com/category/teamcity/tcplugins/tcwebhooks/

Comment: Just noticed you're on TC 9, tcWebHooks maybe having issues since TC 9 brand new.

Comment: I don't think the project settings page is extendible. Or at least at wasn't when I started writing tcWebHooks against TeamCity 4.0.1